# Android tablets design Suggestion

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am new to android tablet design. [image]

This is the home page with its various parts numbered
I wanted to know the best possible design approach. Most sites related to android 4 describe basic use of fragments.

Here i have

- 1 which is fixed and would be available for all the future pages.
- 2 and 6 consists of sliding images.on click i want to show the images in 5
- 3 is the application name tab.Fixed for all pages
- 7 consists of tabs
- 4 consists of sub menu populated when a tab is clicked in 7
- 5 is where i want to show whatever is clicked.

My question is  for such a layout, where should i use fragments and how many.which is the best possible approach.

Say  since 1,3,6,2 are constant .. cant i use a separate XML and include it in the pages.

7 are the tabs. On click of a tab 4 is populated which further populates 5
Should i use fragments for these.

Answer (score 0):

There are many portions in your design. The best designing  style is "make it simple and avoid complexity. You always found some apps which are displaying too many content those apps are not user friendly . Just think which portion of your app is used more and more time and put it in the best position of your design .

Try to minimize the number of tabs . You can put lots of tabs on 7 and also make it scroll-able but its little bit boring to use a tab under scroll . In single activity you can not use multiple xml file with out fragment . Hare is my personal comment :" i think it would be more beautiful if you put number "7" under of over "3" and according to my consideration number "4" is less necessary , "2" and "6" is confusing "

you can see this link :  [Design](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html)

Thank You

Comment: Thanks, Can i use a separate xml for 1 and 3 and include them in all the pages. Will there be any problme?

Comment: 3 is always fixed so you dont do anything with it . for 1 you can not use separate xml .  but you can manage it with fragment